# How to send object of calling activity to called activity

Tags: android

From  activity

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(lamps.this,light_control.class).putExtra("variable",lamps.this);


        startActivity(intent);
```

To Activity

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
         lampvaiable = (lamps)intent.getSerializableExtra("variable");
```

I have to use object of lamp.this activity in light_control.class activity but startActivity(intent) is not getting called .

I am getting  java.io.NotSerializableException

Comment: `putExtra("variable",lamps.this);` -> `putExtra("variable",lamps);`  // the object you want to pass

Comment: it is showing error that expression expected

Answer (score 1):

First of all make class Serializable, the object of which your are sending the

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("variable", (Serializable) Object);
```

Then receive as

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
lamps lamp = (Lamps) intent.getExtras().getSerializable("variable");
```

Comment: I have implemented Serializable for lamps class

Comment: can I use lamps.class

Comment: Where do you want to use lamps.class ?

Comment: in called activity

Comment: Yes for that purpose you need check the Access Specifier of your class whether its public or not ? If yes! then you need to import that class in your destination activity to be able to use its object.

Comment: getting this error 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to in.chipmonk.havellsolarapp.lamps

Answer (score 0):

Use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library for this purpose. Convert a object to string by Gson then send it to another activity. Get that string from intent and convert it to Object

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that bundle can holds onto a max size of arguments (1MB, If I'm not mistaken). If this is a huge object you will get a TransactionTooLargeExceptionexception. So please be advise to consider other methods (Local Storage, DataManager that would hold the object, etc.)